# PayPal Request keep getting MALFORMED_REQUEST

Tags: php, json, api, rest, paypal

I tried to send a payment to PayPal. But for some reason I only get a MALFORMED_REQUEST error. 
There are no more information. Not even with the getData() function for the exception.

Here is the compiled JSON:

```
{
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
        "first_name": "Testvorname",
        "last_name": "Testnachname",
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "suffix": "Herr"
    }
},
"transactions": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "total": "72.00"
        },
        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "quantity": "4",
                    "name": "test1",
                    "price": "8",
                    "currency": "EUR"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "2",
                    "name": "test2",
                    "price": "20",
                    "currency": "EUR"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://www.google.de",
    "cancel_url": "https://www.google.de"
} }
```

I have no Idea what could be wrong with this JSON.
I'm using the PHP SDK.

Comment: The JSON you're showing here validates correctly.  Are you sure that's what's actually getting sent to PayPal?  If you continue to struggle with it you may want to try [this PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead.  It works on the Classic API (which I still prefer and recommend) and does not have any quirky issues like I see quite a bit of with the official PayPal SDK.  Many of the PayPal integration reps actually prefer this SDK, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the SDK. The data that you are passing to the paypal server is causing this issue. The error message was not obvious here though.

You do not need to pass "payer_info" in the "payer" object. Removing that fixes the issue. Here is how the JSON would look like:

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "total": "72.00"
            },
            "item_list": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "quantity": "4",
                        "name": "test1",
                        "price": "8",
                        "currency": "EUR"
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": "2",
                        "name": "test2",
                        "price": "20",
                        "currency": "EUR"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "https://www.google.de",
        "cancel_url": "https://www.google.de"
    }
}
```

For more information you could always use the samples provided in the SDK, and the documentation that helps you quickly help you debug issues, etc.

**Here are some useful links:**

- Running Samples Locally: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples
- Setting up SDKs: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call
- General SDK information: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

Comment: Okay thanks, but whats the point of the payer_info object, if I cant use it?

Comment: It is a part of the response object. You will get the payer info when you complete the paypal express checkout flow in REST API. You can read what fields are acceptable at : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/